# Can I have dual steps in a range, or place two steps in the the range function

Tags: python

Something like this in the range function (0, 1001, 1 and 5? )
My steps would be 1 and 5 from 1-1000?
Or is there an equivalent to produce that sequence of numbers as a list.
Or given a sequence of numbers pre generated create a new sequence of numbers using a dual step acting like stepping stones.
I would hope to see an example that worked, produce, if starting from a list of the numbers from 1-1000 and if the count starts from 0.
1,6,7,12,13,18.
I hope that is clear, I am a complete novice.

Well I have been trying to focus in on what Technical area, I need to solve my problem, as a novice, I am trying to understand the terms used and what these mean.

Answer (score 1):

In general you can use [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) with [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) for these kind of things. For example, this will generate never-ending values alternating between skips of 5 and 1:

```
from itertools import cycle, accumulate

values = accumulate(cycle((5, 1)), initial=1)
# generate 1, 6, 7, 12, 13, 18, 19, 24, 25, … ∞
```

To limit this to a certain range, you can use [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) to pull values off until you hit the end:

```
from itertools import cycle, accumulate, takewhile

values = accumulate(cycle((5, 1)), initial=1)

list(takewhile(lambda n: n < 30, values))
# [1, 6, 7, 12, 13, 18, 19, 24, 25]
```

One nice thing about this is that it scales nicely to more complex patterns:

```
from itertools import cycle, accumulate, takewhile

# skip 5, then 1, then 2, then 1...
values = accumulate(cycle((5, 1, 2, 1)), initial=1)

list(takewhile(lambda n: n < 30, values))
# [1, 6, 7, 9, 10, 15, 16, 18, 19, 24, 25, 27, 28]
```

Comment: Thank you, I will take that away and see how I do.

Answer (score 0):

You want to generate a sequence of numbers that alternates between two step values (like `1` and `5`). The built-in `range` function in Python does not support this feature directly. However, you can achieve this by using a custom generator.

Here's how you can create such a sequence using a custom generator:

```py
def dual_step_range(start, stop, step1, step2):
    i = start
    steps = [step1, step2]

    while i < stop:
        for step in steps:
            if i < stop:
                yield i
                i += step

# Using the generator
sequence_gen = list(dual_step_range(1, 1001, 5, 1))
print(sequence_gen)
```

When executed, this code will output the sequence: `1, 6, 7, 12, 13, 18, ...` up to 1000.

This generator, `dual_step_range`, starts at the `start` value and then alternates between adding `step1` and `step2` to produce the desired sequence.

Comment: Thank you, I will have a go with this too and see how I do.